# Two spring applications, both use a certain jar and application context - how do i control from which appl i get a bean from the context?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jmx, spring-jmx

I have two Spring applications, applA and applB, running in Tomcat - both use jarX.jar and applicationContext-x.xml.
So there's going to be one instance of a certain bean, defined in the above context, for each application.
I'm exposing the bean and some of its methods via JMX by using annotations.
now i want to write a test client which calls method of the bean, but sometimes i want to call the methods of the bean in applA and sometimes of the bean in applB.

How do i do that?
i also have a bean called jmxServerConfiguration in each application, each using a different port though.

currently in my JMX client i'm getting the bean by using

```
BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(applicationContextName);
theBean = beanFactory.getBean(BEAN_NAME);
```

but i always get the bean of applA. how do i tell it whether i want the bean of applB or applA?

Should i perhaps, (how?), use

```
MBeanServerConnection connection = JmxUtils.getMBeanServerConnection(url);
```

and specify a different port in the url, depending on the appl from which i want to get the bean?

Comment: Give different bean ids for each of the bean and access them by id instead of name.

Comment: the id is in the .xml which is in the jar which is included by both applications. is there a way to create an alias to a bean in one of the applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `default-domain` on the MBean exporter to a different value for each application and use the appropriate `ObjectName` to access the bean(s) over JMX.